# What data type should be used for storing frequencies in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-schema, sqldatatypes

I am trying to create an app to schedule operations. The schedules can be like - Once in 3 HOURS, once in 5 DAYS etc. I am using SQL Server to store these definitions.

What would be the best way to store the frequencies? I was thinking of XML. But SQL Server doesn't seem to allow GROUP BY on XML (which I desire to use).

Is there some other data type which can better solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I would have thought it more a matter of schema design rather than simply "data type"

Comment: How would you design the schema in that case? Would you split this data into multiple columns?

Comment: Is "once in 5 days" meant to be "every 120 hours" or "at the same time of day every 5 days"? In the presence of daylight savings time adjustments, the two aren't the same. Time handling can be remarkably complex.

Comment: It is meant to be every 120 hours.

Comment: "once in 5 days" is not "datatypeable", it's a semantic representation in language. So you'd either need to reduce the frequency to the smallest entity (hour for example) and store that which makes it more simple for you, or you need to invent some business logic to handle it for you and then need to split acorss multiple columns/functions - personally, I'd opt for saving frequency in an number (integer) of the smallest time possible.